# why isn't jdatepicker object is showing in gui jframe

Tags: java, swing

`Datepicker` isn't showing in gui jframe but when i create a new `jframe` and add datepicker in it then it is showing there but actually i want to show datepicker in same jframe where my other component is displaying
tell me where m doing wrong? please.
this is my code:

```
{   
initComponents();
this.pack();
try {
conn =DriverManager.getConnection(Conn_URL,USER, PASS);
stmt=conn.createStatement();                 
this.sql_Query = "SELECT BILL1.ID , BILL.CUSTOMER_NAME , BILL1.P_NAME , BILL1.PRICE , BILL1.TOTAL from BILL1 INNER JOIN BILL ON BILL1.ID=BILL.BILL_ID";     
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql_Query);                 
this.jTable1.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Bill ID");              
jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("Customer Name");                
jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue("Product Name");
jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setHeaderValue("Price");
      jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setHeaderValue("Total");    
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        } 
        catch(SQLException ex) 
        {
         Logger.getLogger(salereport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("text.today", "Today");
    p.put("text.month", "Month");

    p.put("text.year", "Year");

    UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();

    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model,p);

    JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,new DateLabelFormatter());
    this.add(datePicker);
 }
```

Comment: Do you revalidate, or update the layout in any fashion? What layout does ''this'' have.

Comment: no i didnt update any layout for this..

Comment: "*but when i create a new jframe and add datepicker in it then it is showing there but actually i want to show datepicker in same jframe where my other component is*" - Every component that you can successfully add directly to the frame you can also add to a `JPanel`. Your main panel can also contain multiple panels with different layouts. (that would solve the problem with multiple components) Did you try that?

Comment: but i didnt have any jpanel in frame.

Comment: Then it's time to do so. I guess that `this` is a JFrame, so `datePicker` is added  to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of it (therefore overlaying the previous component). Without setting [layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and without (nested) panels you don't have many options...

Comment: no its not a problem because i just add jpanel in jframe and then add datepicker in it but still it's not showing. Actually any compnent whether its a button or else jpanel isn't showing it.

Comment: Then please post a runnable [mcve] or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) of your problem (as an edit), because we can't reproduce it yet.

Comment: well i was not setting its layout thats why it is not showing.

Comment: can you please help me in one more situation in the same code when i run it calendar is showing under jframe but i want to show calendar under texfield how can i do tha

Comment: You didn't provide a [mcve] or a pic/ASCII-art of the intended look - So I can't know how exactly you want it to look like. The easiest way would be to add the textfield to `BorderLayout.NORTH` and the calendar to `BorderLayout.CENTER`

Comment: You've packed the window and then tried to updated it ... it's likely that not only does the container/layout manager not now that the component has no been added, it may also be unable to show based on the available space.  It's also unclear as to what layout manager you are using, which could also have influences over the desired out come of your UI